# Space around images and menu bar

Tags: html, css

Around my pictures and menu bar I have a little bit of space and I would like to get rid of that. I tried to set the margin to 0 but that didn't work. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

[this is an image of the result that i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0YoN.jpg)

```html
<!doctype html>
     <html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css">
 </head>
 
    <body>
    <p id="Anouk"><img src="logo/Hout.png" width="1000px" alt="Logo"/></p>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="menu">
            <!--Home-->
            <li id="home"><a href="index.html"><img src="Iconen/Home.png" height="80px" alt="home" onmouseover="this.src='Iconen/Home2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Iconen/Home.png'"/></a></li>
            <!--Over Mij-->
         <li id="over"><a href="over.html"><img src="Iconen/Over.png" height="80px" alt="home" onmouseover="this.src='Iconen/Over2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Iconen/Over.png'"/></a></li>
         <!--Portfolio-->
            <li id="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.html"><img src="Iconen/Portfolio.png" height="80px" alt="home" onmouseover="this.src='Iconen/Portfolio2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Iconen/Portfolio.png'"/></a></li>
            <!--Contact-->
            <li id="contact"><a href="contact.html"><img src="Iconen/Contact.png" height="80px" alt="home" onmouseover="this.src='Iconen/Contact2.png'"onmouseout="this.src='Iconen/Contact.png'"/></a></li>               
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

body {
    background-color: #ADF1F5;
}

#Anouk {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
    height: 80px;
    background: #000000;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
 height: 80px;
}

#contact {
 float: right;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a working jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you show your full code here , The parent div in which you are having menu is having some padding or margin that,s why gap is coming ,if you are able to show the full html code of page we can easily fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### li's

```
li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

this should do the trick.

Why does that happen?
The browser interprets line breaks in the code as spaces, in result of that inline and inline-block elements - those which respect the spaces - are spaced from another.
block elements do not respect them.

---

### image

possible issues:
Browser padding/margin, add the following to your css

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

your `<p id="Anouk">` should have a margin, use a `<div>` for non content elements

```
<div id="Anouk"><img src="logo/Hout.png" width="1000px" alt="Logo"/></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, do you also know how to fix the space between the image on top of the page and the menu bar and the top op the page?